# Adding build_last_value_tracker feature to Logstash ElasticSearch input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, logstash

Come across the solution here and I have some questions:
[Logstash Elasticsearch Input Plugin for streaming data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097846/logstash-elasticsearch-input-plugin-for-streaming-data/39098551#39098551?newreg=fee3b819709342f081d6a72401702cd6)

Where should the last run time be recorded? I'm thinking to record it in a text file and read it from file input plugin, re-calculate it in filter plugin, then write the new value out in output file plugin. But I have concerns of multi-worker concurrent processing in logstash pipeline.
Checked out jdbc input plugin build_last_value_tracker implementation. Is that multi-worker concurrent processing safe?
Should we fork from the existing elasticsearch input plugin and extend it with build_last_value_tracker like what we have in jdbc input plugin?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the jdbc input plugin, the build_last_value_tracker is managed internally by the  plugin. So if you want the same functionality in the elasticsearch input plugin, you need to modify the plugin itself, there's no way to implement the same functionality with input/output file plugins. A similar need has been recorded [in this issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/issues/93), without much traction.

Comment: [Another issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/issues/184) with the same need

Comment: Hi Val, thank you for the comments. Is the implementation in JDBC multi-worker concurrent processing safe? It seems all the workers will read and write to the same file.

Comment: Whenever the `jdbc` input kicks in (based on schedule), the value tracking file is read, the statement is run to pick up where it left during the last run and the rows are [fanned out](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/main/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb#L316) to all workers for further processing. If you have several `jdbc` inputs, each input should have [its own value tracking file](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/main/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb#L98C3-L102C45) to prevent undesired behavior.